# I need to remove Open meta graph from my theme

Tags: php, wordpress, web, themes

I'm currently using the Zox News theme along with the premium version of SEOpress. I've encountered an issue where the Zox News theme is generating duplicate meta information, including Twitter, Facebook, Open Graph (OG) description, and OG title. I would like to completely remove the Open Graph meta. Your assistance with this matter would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

I found a scource code but not sure what to delete it It would be great if someone helps me.. I have a child theme please provide a necessary code which i can add it to function.php file, so the next time when i update theme it won't get deleted. Here is the theme code

```
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>" >
<meta name="viewport" id="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=5.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes" />
<?php if ( ! function_exists( 'has_site_icon' ) || ! has_site_icon() ) { if(get_option('mvp_favicon')) { ?><link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo esc_url(get_option('mvp_favicon')); ?>" /><?php } } ?>
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo('pingback_url'); ?>" />
<?php if ( is_single() ) { ?>
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php if (  (function_exists('has_post_thumbnail')) && (has_post_thumbnail())  ) { ?>
        <?php $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'mvp-post-thumb' ); ?>
        <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo esc_url( $thumb['0'] ); ?>" />
        <meta name="twitter:image" content="<?php echo esc_url( $thumb['0'] ); ?>" />
    <?php } ?>
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php the_permalink() ?>" />
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" />
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo strip_tags(get_the_excerpt()); ?>" />
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta name="twitter:url" content="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="<?php echo strip_tags(get_the_excerpt()); ?>">
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
<?php } else { ?>
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php bloginfo('description'); ?>" />
<?php } ?>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of code that clearly shows integration of Open Graph tags:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php the_permalink() ?>" />
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" />
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo strip_tags(get_the_excerpt()); ?>" />
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta name="twitter:url" content="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="<?php echo strip_tags(get_the_excerpt()); ?>">
```

Just remove them and test using view-source.

Comment: thank you for the reply. However, when I remove that code from the header file, it shows an error stating, 'The website has encountered a critical error

Comment: Just skip the below lines, I have updated the above answer. Try removing these lines only.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for the reply. However, when I remove that code from the header file, it shows an error stating, 'The website has encountered a critical error

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

To remove the Open Graph (OG) meta tags from your Zox News theme, you can add the following code snippet to your child theme's '**functions.php**' file:

```
function remove_open_graph_meta() {
    remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_graph_do_meta_boxes');
}
add_action('init', 'remove_open_graph_meta');
```

This code snippet will remove the Open Graph meta tags generated by the theme. By adding this code to your child theme's '**functions.php**' file, you ensure that the modifications won't be lost when you update the theme.

Make sure to save the changes and clear any cache if necessary. This should resolve the issue of duplicate meta information and help improve your SEO.